# Create facsimile entries for all records stemming from a single reocrd within a parent table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which below object level is self-constructing or at least it creates and alters sibling tables as and when required and creates a relation between the table and the objects table.

```
Structure:
<Projects>
  - id _______     <collections>
  ....       |       - id  ______________   <objects>                <some_object>
             |_____> - project_id       |     - id___________________>
                      ....              |___> - collection_id   |    <some_other_object>
                                                 ....           |___>
                                                                |
                                                               ....
```

Can anyone suggest a succinct method of creating a copy of each entry linked to a give collections record, which in turn would be linked to a new collections record?

Each of the  tables have an object_id column which has a foreign key constraint to objects.id, the rest of the table structure is likely to differ.

Take the following example:

```
|Collections|
------------------
|  id  |  Title  |
------------------
|  1   | Col1    |
|  2   | Col2    |
------------------

|Objects|
--------------------------------------------
|  id  |  Collection_id  |   Object Type    |
--------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   1             |  Classification  |
|  2   |   1             |  Space           |
|  3   |   2             |  Classification  |
--------------------------------------------|
```

The self-constructing element creates a table with the name of the Object type. This won't affect the approach but should make the next part of the example a less confusing.

```
|Classification (or other self-constructing table)|
------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  object_id      |   Some column    | ,,,  |  ,,,  |
--------------------------------------------|---------------
|  1   |   1             |  val             |
|  2   |   1             |  val             |
|  3   |   2             |  val             |
--------------------------------------------|
```

So with the above records say we were looking to create a facsimile of "Col1" from collections and its dependents, we'll say the new collection.id = 3.

The resulting table structure would be as follows.

```
|Collections|
------------------
|  id  |  Title  |
------------------
|  1   | Col1    |
|  2   | Col2    |
|  3   | Col1    |
------------------

|Objects|
--------------------------------------------
|  id  |  Collection_id  |   Object Type    |
--------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   1             |  Classification  |
|  2   |   1             |  Space           |
|  3   |   2             |  Classification  |
|  4   |   3             |  Classification  |
|  5   |   3             |  Space           |
--------------------------------------------|

|Classification (or other self-constructing table)|
------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  object_id      |   Some column    | ,,,  |  ,,,  |
--------------------------------------------|---------------
|  1   |   1             |  val             |
|  2   |   1             |  val             |
|  3   |   2             |  val             |
|  4   |   4             |  val             |
|  5   |   4             |  val             |
|  6   |   5             |  val             |
--------------------------------------------|
```

Effectively cloning the entire object structure and it's children for a given node (node used as id)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish?  The question is a bit vague as is.